# Two Fuel Pumps died

Tags: electrical, starting, fuel-system, fuel-pump

Already having replaced 2 fuel pumps, both died.

Seems to have a problem in somewhere (alternator, battery, electricity) or I have no luck for fuel pumps.

The last one, last 6 months, before died completely, it start making a loud noises.

Vehicle: Dodge Charger SRT8 2009

On both fuel pump connectors there is a burned corner pin. No one in garage can tell me what is wrong with that.

[image: fuel pump connector]

Anyone got an idea what can it be ?

**** **UPDATED QUESTION** ****

So, after having tested an electricity, everything was fine, except that battery is about to die, but that's not a case. Alternator works fine, relay is fine, cable management should be fixed for the fuel pump, but that's just for a better future use.

The problem was: Somehow the fuel tank was extremely dirty, fuel pump engine died completely and the whole left part of fuel pump assembly was dirty, fuel pump filter was almost totally black from that dirt.

[image]
[image]

Now I think to go back to the garage where they previously cleaned my fuel tank, to do it in a proper way. In a meanwhile I have to order a new fuel pump.

Question is: is that possible that a dirt could make a pin to be burned ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dirt in the tank could definitely be the cause of the burned pin because the burned pin suggests that the pump was drawing a larger than normal current from that wire.  The pump having to contend with dirt in the tank could mean it was having to work significantly harder than when pumping clean fuel which would be a very good reason for it to draw excessive amounts of electrical current.  This additional current manifest in a significantly hotter temperature in the wiring and connectors and would explain the visual charring on the connector.

Comment: And the most freaky question to ask: Could that dirty fuel tank damage the engine ? Vehicle was running for 6 months on the last fuel pump, so the dirt was collecting since then. As long the engine was working, while pushing on the gas pedal, the vehicle started to struggle for 2 last months. Could it damage something in the engine ?

Comment: In theory it could but it's unlikely.  It would however be worth replacing your inline fuel filters as there is a chance the debris from the tank may be fowling these.  They're not expensive so well worth replacing once your tank is clean.

Comment: Thank you Steve, I would look for that "inline fuel filters" then.

Answer (score 6):

Voltage drop the ground side pin 4 with the car running. I'd suspect a poor ground is the cause.

You can also scope the power side by removing the fuse and putting a wire loop in place. Connect a low amp probe. Since the fuse is rated @ 20A you should expect to see 8-10A if it's drawing more amps than that suspect a short to ground or a bad ground or corrosion in a connector.

Comment: Thank you Ben for your tips. I hardly understand what you are saying as I am zero at electricity, but what I saw the dude was doing, I can clearly say that he did exactly the same thing you proposed to me. And YES, there was a corrosion in a connector, while at the same time a DIRT somehow came into the fuel tank and damaged fuel pump within it's fuel pump filter.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason for burnt connectors could be from cargo or passengers sitting in the back seat on the driver's side.  The weight on the seat cracks the plastic fuel pump cover and wiggles the connector causing the pins to heat up.  If left too long, the pins will melt the plastic around them causing gas to leak through the connector.  This happened to me twice, 5 months apart and at $165 per fuel pump I'm glad the second one was under warranty.  I made an aluminum cover plate which solved the problem.  Haven't had any issues for a year.   Check out:  https://www.fuelconnectorfire.com/

Comment: wow, incredible attention to details from manufacturer...

Comment: Perhaps the manufacturers design to the average mass of the passengers , not the maximum possible...

Comment: What ever average mass they used, they were wrong.