# Four fuel pumps in one month?

Tags: dodge, ram, fuel-pump

Since December 25 of 2023 to date I have replaced four fuel filters in my Dodge 1500 hemi. I don’t understand why they keep failing. The last one literally lasted a week, no sorry wasn’t even a week it was four days and it died and I cannot figure out why I keep going through fuel pumps. It’s all of a sudden just one after another quite literally. The truck’s got really high mileage like 300,000.

Comment: Can you just clarify, it is 4 fuel pumps, not fuel filters? Most places you say pumps, but in one place you say filter

Comment: What fails on the pumps?  Is it the electric motor or the pump mechanics?  Does the pump turn, but no fuel is pumped, or has the motor stopped turning?

Comment: What year is your vehicle? Which engine?

Comment: Also take a look at this post (dirty fuel tank seemed to be the culprit): https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/28447/two-fuel-pumps-died?rq=1